# How to use submitHandler as string in jquery validator

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using rules, messages and `errorElement` as string

```
var rules = '{"rules":{"hotel_name":{"required": true}},"messages":{"hotel_name":{"required": "some message"}}, "errorElement": "span"}';
```

and passing it to

```
var validator = $('#create_hotels').validate(JSON.parse(rules));
```

It is working fine but If I use `submitHandler` in the string above it doesn't work
I am using it this way

```
var rules = '{"rules":{"hotel_name":{"required": true}},"messages":{"hotel_name":{"required": "some message"}}, "errorElement": "span", "submitHandler": "function(form){ajax_function(form);}"}';
```

Ajax function I am calling in submitHandler

```
     function ajax_function(form){
        var formData = $(form).serialize();

        $.ajax({
          url: form.action,
          type: form.method,
          data: {"data":formData},
          headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')},
          dataType: "html",
          success: function(response) {
            var jsonObj = JSON.parse(response);              
            if(jsonObj.success == true)
            {
              $("#submit_success_msg_div").fadeIn().html('<i id="submit_success_msg_icon" class="icon fas fa-check"></i>'+jsonObj.message);
              setTimeout(function(){ 
                $("#submit_success_msg_div").fadeOut();
              }, 3000);

            }else if(jsonObj.success == false)
            {
              $("#submit_fail_msg_div").fadeIn().html('<i id="submit_fail_msg_icon" class="fas fa-times"></i> Sorry hotel was not created');
              setTimeout(function(){ 
                $("#submit_fail_msg_div").fadeOut();
              }, 3000);
            }
          }            
        });
      }
```

It is necessary for me to do it this way, please guide why submit handler not working this way while others working ?

Comment: You cannot put a function reference in to JSON as a string. There is no workaround for this.

Comment: ok If I don't put it in string and use it normal way, how should I write it please show example

Comment: Add the function reference to a property on the object after you parse it, eg `jsonObj.submitHandler = function(form){ ajax_function(form); }`

Comment: I am sorry I didn't get it I request you please show me in proper answer that will be great help